# Using 'collection_select' with an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display an array in drop down list using `collection_select`. My array is:

```
"[\"\", \"Jacket\", \"Shirt\"]"
```

The code is below:

```
<%= form.collection_select(:parts, @parts, :to_s, include_blank: false,prompt:"Select the part" )%>
```

I get an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for "[\"\", \"jacket\", \"shirt\"]":String
Did you mean?  tap):
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's a string and that's why you get this error.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your "array" isn't an array, but a JSON string.

If you parse the json string to an array this should work.

```
parsed = JSON.parse("[\"\", \"Jacket\", \"Shirt\"]")
```

Comment: @sawa That was a brainfart from my side, thanks for spotting that. Removed it